# Gradle: using task's member as an other task's input

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

setVersionTask sets a member that I want to be used as input by getVersionTask. Here's my code:

```
class TaskA extends DefaultTask {
    @InputFile
    File pbxprojectFile
    @Optional
    String version

    @TaskAction
    void exec() {
        this.version  "version_set"
    }
}

class TaskB extends DefaultTask {
    @Input
    String version
}

task setVersionTask(type: TaskA){
    pbxprojectFile project.file('foo.txt')
}

task getVersionTask(type: TaskB){
    doFirst{
        println('version ' + setVersionTask.version)
    }
    version setVersionTask.version
    dependsOn 'setVersionTask'
}
```

When I go

> ./gradlew -q getVersion

I get

A problem was found with the configuration of task ':getVersionTask'.
No value has been specified for property 'version'.

How do I accomplish that?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Why do you want to set the `version` property during the execution phase rather than the configuration phase? See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html for info on the build lifecycle.

Comment: Simply because it's not defined initially. It gets a value after taskA has  run.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to set TaskB's version from TaskA's doLast:

```
task setVersionTask(type: TaskA){
    pbxprojectFile project.file('foo.txt')
    doLast{
        getVersionTask.version = version
    }
}

task getVersionTask(type: TaskB){
    doFirst{
        println('version ' + getVersionTask.version)
    }
    dependsOn 'setVersionTask'
}
```